# where members can buy certain products with only reward points

Tags: opencart

I'm setting up a new store but was wondering the following:

I would like to setup a "member-area" where members can buy certain products with only reward points, so that no price is mentioned, only the number of reward points needed.

Can anyone guide me in a right direction?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using customer groups, customers, the special price of products, and reward points.
Go to admin >> Customers >> Customer Groups and make a new customer group called "Member Only"
[image: Customer Group]

Now go to admin >> Customers >> Customers then edit the customer and assign customers to the "Member Only" groups.

[image: Customers]

Now, go to admin >> Catalog >> Products >> edit the products and enter the details and at the "Special" tab you can assign a price for each customer group.

[image: Special price in Opencart]

Click Save and the customer group assigned to "Member Only" will see a different price than the default customer

Now finally match the reward points as per the price.
[image: Reward points in Opencart]

With this, the customer can apply the reward points on the cart page.

[Opencart user guide](https://webocreation.com/blog/how-to-build-a-free-ecommerce-website-using-opencart-3-user-manual-in-2020/)